# rosrun cannot find specified node file

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using electric on Ubuntu 11.10

I recently created a new package and node.
Something I have done before with no problems.

```
roscreate-pkg my_package rospy std_msgs
```

There were no errors with rosmake.

When I go to run the node I wrote via

```
rosrun my_package my_node.py
```

I get "No such file or directory" despite the file being in /my_workspace/my_package/nodes/my_node.py

The file is in place and set as executable, ros can find and build the package but will not run my node.

The only edits I made to the CMakeList.txt file were to uncomment the rosbuild_genmsg() and rosbuild_gensrv() lines.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40551/rosrun-cannot-find-specified-node-file/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had this problem before, it's bizarre and I'm not sure what *causes* the problem, but I do think that I know how to solve it.  For me at least, the problem was specific to the file; other files in the package could run fine.  My solution was to re-create the node file, and copy-paste the contents. You will (hopefully) find that it now works.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If rosrun does not find an executable, it reports:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named test below
```

and not:

```
No such file or directory
```

rosrun is a short bash script that you can examine for debugging:

```
 cat /opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosrun
```

You can copy the rosrun file and modify the copy for debugging. I would guess the error should be reproducable with

```
exec /home/path/to/your/node/my_node.py
```

which is the last line of rosrun. You can add the line:

echo $exepath

before the last line in rosrun to see whether there is any problem with the path.

Also you can run the find command in isolation:

```
find -L `${ROS_ROOT}/bin/rospack find my_package` -name my_node.py -type f  -perm +111 ! -regex ".*$pkgdir\/build\/.*"
```

To see whether that returns something weird (replace my_package and my_node.py if you have different names).

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2